# PyQt5 - Add image in background of MainWindow layout

Tags: python-3.x, qwidget, pyqt5, qimage, qlayout

New to PyQt5... Here is a very basic question.

I would like to add an image inside the layout of a widget. This widget is the Main Window / root widget of my application. I use the following code, but I get an error message.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

       super().__init__()

       self.setGeometry(300,300,300,220)
       self.setWindowTitle("Hello !")

       oImage = QImage("backgound.png")

       oLayout = QVBoxLayout()
       oLayout.addWidget(oImage)

       self.setLayout(oLayout)

       self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    oMainwindow = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


TypeError: QBoxLayout.addWidget(QWidget, int stretch=0, Qt.Alignment alignment=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QImage'
```

Apparently a QLayoutWidget does not accept a QImage as an input. Is there a workaround to have an image appear as a brackground in a QWidget ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The QVBoxLayout class lines up widgets vertically.

[documentation QVBoxLayout](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvboxlayout.html#details)

`QImage` is no widget.

on many widgets e.g. `QmainWindow`, `QLabel` you can use

```
widget.setStyleSheet(„ background-image: url(backgound.png);“)
```

on my machine this doesn't work with `QWidget`. In this case you can use the following rewrite of your code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPalette, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
       QWidget.__init__(self)
       self.setGeometry(100,100,300,200)

       oImage = QImage("test.png")
       sImage = oImage.scaled(QSize(300,200))                   # resize Image to widgets size
       palette = QPalette()
       palette.setBrush(QPalette.Window, QBrush(sImage))                        
       self.setPalette(palette)

       self.label = QLabel('Test', self)                        # test, if it's really backgroundimage
       self.label.setGeometry(50,50,200,50)

       self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    oMainwindow = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The code with setPalette works well with my MainWindow. Now the MainWindow also contains a QTabWiget and I am trying to set images in the background of these QTabWidget pages. I tried with setPalette and setStyleSheet, but none seemt work. Is it possible to set images as backgrounds of other widgets, not only windows ? The following do not work:  `MyPage.setStyleSheet("background-image: url(myimage.jpg);")`  and   `MyPage.setPalette(palette)`

Comment: I can setStyleSheet on QTabWidget as well as on a page (QWidget). If you can't solve it, you should ask a new question with your code.

Comment: I created a new question with my new code here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468937/pyqt5-image-as-background-for-qtabwidgetpage

Comment: I tried this code but the background image is not displayed, instead it shows black screen with my buttons on the screen. 
Any solution ?

Comment: do you have test.png in your working dir? are there any error messages in console?

Comment: resurrecting old thread but i also only have a black image, the background is loaded properly with a test and the image is in the working dir

Comment: code is still working for me if "test.png" is in working dir. i get a black sreen and the message "QImage::scaled: Image is a null image" if there is no "test.png".