# Impossible to add a background-image in parent QWidget with PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I've been struggling with this for the last 2 days... I would like to simply add a stretched background image to my parent QWidget. I literally tried a dozens of times after searching everywhere but I'm still stuck with this issue. I don't use resources (from qt designer). PSB :

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys

class Ui_Form(QtWidgets.QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
    self.setupUi(self) 

def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.setObjectName("Form")
    Form.resize(860, 619)
    Form.setStyleSheet("QWidget#Form {border-image: url(space.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;}")
```

And it does not work (default BG displayed). But when I execute this:

```
        Form.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(space.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;")
```

All Qwidgets children get the background which is obviously not what I want. But it proves at least that there is no problem with the resource itself. I cannot believe that some basic features like setting an background image is not supported in PyQt5... and appearantly I'm not the only one :

[StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35432125/6237999)

I've tried to make it work via Qpalette() and it works better but I don't know how to make the background image stretched =/ :

```
    image = QtGui.QImage("space.png")
    palette = QtGui.QPalette()
    palette.setBrush(10, QtGui.QBrush(image))     

    Form.setPalette(palette)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: try `Form.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(space.png);")`....by the way hope you don't execute `setStyleSheet` twice (in the init method and somewhere else)

Comment: Thx for your reply @danidee. I tried your command and unfortunately the image is applied to all the parent's children (1 hlayout and 2 QGroupBox). Even after commenting all the `setStyleSheet` of my Widget application that I have for some of my QpushButton or QGroupBox, I face the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (with the help of Qt Forum). I took a look at [Qt Style Sheets Examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html) and could not find how to customize a QWidget so I simply convert my QWidget to a QMainWindow. I got rid of the menu bar and the status bar because I don't need them... everything works fine now with QMainWindow :)

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self):
  super().__init__()       
  self.setupUi(self)

def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
  MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
  MainWindow.resize(856, 610)
  MainWindow.setStyleSheet("#MainWindow { border-image: url(space.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch; }")
  self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
  self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
```